# AWS CloudFormation Stack Creation Keeps Failing

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to create a DynamoDB table using a CloudFormation stack, however I keep receiving the 'CREATE_FAILED' error in the AWS console and I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

My method to create_stack:

```
cf = boto3.client('cloudformation')
stack_name = 'teststack'

with open('dynamoDBTemplate.json') as json_file:
    template = json.load(json_file)
    template = str(template)

try:
    response = cf.create_stack(
        StackName = stack_name,
        TemplateBody = template,
        TimeoutInMinutes = 123,
        ResourceTypes = [
            'AWS::DynamoDB::Table',
        ],
        OnFailure = 'DO_NOTHING',
        EnableTerminationProtection = True
    )
    print(response)
except ClientError as e:
    print(e)
```

And here is my JSON file:

```
{
   "AWSTemplateFormatVersion":"2010-09-09",
   "Resources":{
      "myDynamoDBTable":{
         "Type":"AWS::DynamoDB::Table",
         "Properties":{
            "AttributeDefinitions":[
               {
                  "AttributeName":"Filename",
                  "AttributeType":"S"
               },
               {
                  "AttributeName":"Positive Score",
                  "AttributeType":"S"
               },
               {
                  "AttributeName":"Negative Score",
                  "AttributeType":"S"
               },
               {
                  "AttributeName":"Mixed Score",
                  "AttributeType":"S"
               }
            ],
            "KeySchema":[
               {
                  "AttributeName":"Filename",
                  "KeyType":"HASH"
               }
            ],
            "ProvisionedThroughput":{
               "ReadCapacityUnits":"5",
               "WriteCapacityUnits":"5"
            },
            "TableName":"testtable"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

My console prints the created stack but there is no clear indication in the console as to why it keeps failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the Events tab for your stack. It will show you the detailed actions and explain which step first failed. Specifically it will tell you:

> One or more parameter values were invalid: Number of attributes in KeySchema does not exactly match number of attributes defined in AttributeDefinitions (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: 12345; Proxy: null)

The problem is that you have provided definitions for all of your table attributes. You should only provide the key attributes.

Per the [AttributeDefinitions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-dynamodb-table.html#cfn-dynamodb-table-attributedefinitions) documentation:

> [AttributeDefinitions is] A list of attributes that describe the key schema for the table and indexes.